# Getting my hand dirty on telepot and facing issues

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have got some got that I picked from here and there and few months back it worked fine however recently when I was returning to my project the code gives out an error and I am not even a beginner in python just trying to learn as I go.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/soumyadeep/Downloads/telepot.py", line 2, in 
    <module>
    import telepot, time
    File "/home/soumyadeep/Downloads/telepot.py", line 38, in 
    <module>
    bot = telepot.Bot('Token')
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'telepot' has no 
    attribute 'Bot' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

is the error and the code is

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import telepot, time

    def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)

    if (content_type == 'text'):
    command = msg['text']
    print ('Got command: %s' % command)

    if  '/hello' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Hello, do you have any commands for today?")
    if '/iamsudo' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Hello, Soumyadeep. How can I assist you today?")
    if '/iamroot' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Hello, Soumyadeep. How can I assist you today?")
    if '/NodeRed' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Let me help you with that. Initiating in some time.")
    if '/name' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "You can call me Ether.")
    if '/master' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "I am a roughly done bot from Soumyadeep Chatterjee.")
    if '/mother' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Requesting initiation.")
    if  '/start' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Hello. What can I assist you with?")
    if  '/delta' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Initiating delta sequence. Awaiting authorization from home server.") 
    if  '/goodnight' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Initiating do no disturb throughout the network. ")
    if  '/goodmorning' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Good morning, love. Refreshing the network.")
    if  '/goodbye' in command:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Have a good day, love. Starting a lockdown on the home server.")


    # Creates a bot using the token provided by BotFather
    bot = telepot.Bot('Token')

    # Add the handle function to be called every new received                 
    message
    bot.message_loop(handle)

    # Wait for new messages
    while 1:
    time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what you did.  You have a file called `telepot.py` that is doing `import telepot`.  You can't do that.  That is a circular import.  If you have a module called `telepot`, then you must change your program's file name to something else.

And by the way, your long list of `if` statements should be `if`/`elif`/`elif`/`elif`...  If the message is always going to START with that, then it would be much smarter to put all of those messages in a dictionary and do a single lookup based on the first word.

Comment: Hey, changing the name worked like a charm. Thank you so much for this. I am just getting started so to be honest I am not sure about the if/elif part that you mentioned. I have to see what it means and how to implement it on this piece If you have any suggestions for any article or any YT channel then please do let me know so that I can get my hands on it and learn more.

Comment: You have a long list of `if` statements.  Even if one matches, all the rest will still be checked.  That's wasteful.  Change all but the first one to `elif` instead, that way as soon as one matches, it won't check the rest.  And if this answered your question, you should mark it as answered.